# Eclipse Wildfly Server Runtime fails when using domain

Tags: eclipse, wildfly

I just install the Jboss Tools into Eclipse Mars and tried using the Wildfly 10.0 Runtime.  I've configured the runtime to use domain mode but when I try to start my app, I'm getting the error:

```
11:18:07,344 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.0.Final
11:18:07,564 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
11:18:07,618 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.0.0.CR5 (WildFly Core 2.0.5.Final) starting
11:18:07,871 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:131)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:356)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,1]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:4.0}domain'
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:123)
    ... 3 more

11:18:07,872 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
11:18:07,873 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested.
11:18:07,883 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 10.0.0.CR5 (WildFly Core 2.0.5.Final) stopped in 6ms
```

I don't get this problem when I use standalone mode but I need domain mode to test my app.  Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Have you tried a newer version of WildFly 10? 10.0.0.Final has been released. It looks like the XML is wrong though.

Comment: Thanks, but no.  The same thing happens with 10.0.0.Final.  What XML?  Widlfly starts fine when I run it from the command line so it isn't any one the "normal" configuration XML files (i.e. domain.xml, host.xml, etc.)

Comment: If it works from the command line I'd guess something is wrong with JBoss Tools.

Answer (score 0):

indeed, the 'launch configuration' built by the jBoss server runtime plug-in/tool is wrong for a **Domain**-mode start.

You can fix it as follows:

1. Create the server as usual and its associated runtime (in the Eclipse servers' view > right-click > new > server). When creating the **runtime**, pay attention to specify the 'server base directory' as "domain" (the default is "standalone") and then 'configuration file' as "domain.xml"
2. In the servers' view, right-click the just created jBoss server and do 'Open'. Under the category 'General Information' there is a link to 'Open Launch Configuration'
3. You need to adjust the launch configuration to match the actual launch made by the domain.bat / domain.sh. Of course, you'll need to adjust all paths below:

*DO NOT forget to check OUT the option 'Always update arguments related to the runtime'*

**Program arguments:**

```
-mp "C:/jBOSS/EAP70/modules" org.jboss.as.process-controller -jboss-home "C:\jBOSS\EAP70" -jvm "C:\java\JDK8U66\jre\bin\java" -mp "C:/jBOSS/EAP70/modules" -- "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:/jBOSS/EAP70/domain/log/boot.log" "-Dlogging.configuration=file:/C:/jBOSS/EAP70/domain/configuration/logging.properties" -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -server -- -default-jvm "C:\java\JDK8U66\jre\bin\java"
```

**VM arguments:**

```
-Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -server "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:/jBOSS/EAP70/domain/log/boot.log" "-Dlogging.configuration=file:/C:/jBOSS/EAP70/domain/configuration/logging.properties" -cp "C:\jBOSS\EAP70\jboss-modules.jar" -Djboss.home.dir=C:/jBOSS/EAP70 -Djboss.bind.address.management=localhost
```

**Working Directory:** C:/jBOSS/EAP70/bin

**Main class:** org.jboss.modules.Main

**Classpath:** (bootstrap) JRE system Library + (user entries) jboss-modules.jar

**If you are curious to understand where the trick is**: In the long java command line, there is a separation around the main java class to launch, where "VM arguments" stand on the right of it, and "program arguments" on the left of it. You may capture the actual complete java command line that launches your server in domain mode with a tool like Microsoft *sysinternals process-explorer* on Windows, or the `pargs` shell command in LINUX, after you have started jBOSS with `domain.bat` or `domain.sh`.

But you will observe here that the java command takes a "-jar *module*.jar" argument whereas Eclipse launch requires a conventional "-cp *module*.jar *main-class*" argument form. the '-jar' argument is indeed a variant spec where the main class is specified by the manifest file inside the jar.

In my case, the (very long) command line was:

```
C:\jBOSS\EAP70\bin>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\java"  -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -server  "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:\jBOSS\EAP70\domain\log\process-controller.log"  "-Dlogging.configuration=file:C:\jBOSS\EAP70\domain\configuration/logging.properties"     -jar "C:\jBOSS\EAP70\jboss-modules.jar"          -mp "C:\jBOSS\EAP70\modules"      org.jboss.as.process-controller     -jboss-home "C:\jBOSS\EAP70"     -jvm "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\java"          -mp "C:\jBOSS\EAP70\modules"     --     "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:\jBOSS\EAP70\domain\log\host-controller.log"     "-Dlogging.configuration=file:C:\jBOSS\EAP70\domain\configuration/logging.properties"     -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -server     --     -default-jvm "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\java"
```

which breaks as follows:

```
JAVA_COMMAND>> "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\java"
VM_ARGS_____>> -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -server  "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:\jBOSS\EAP70\domain\log\process-controller.log"  "-Dlogging.configuration=file:C:\jBOSS\EAP70\domain\configuration/logging.properties"
MAIN_CLASS__>> -jar "C:\jBOSS\EAP70\jboss-modules.jar" >>EQUIVALENT>> -cp "C:\jBOSS\EAP70\jboss-modules.jar" org.jboss.modules.Main
PROGRAM-ARGS>> -mp "C:\jBOSS\EAP70\modules"      org.jboss.as.process-controller     -jboss-home "C:\jBOSS\EAP70"     -jvm "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\java"          -mp "C:\jBOSS\EAP70\modules"     --     "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:\jBOSS\EAP70\domain\log\host-controller.log"     "-Dlogging.configuration=file:C:\jBOSS\EAP70\domain\configuration/logging.properties"     -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -server     --     -default-jvm "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\java"
```

From the point you understand this quite surprising program argument section that replicates many of the JVM aguments, you can then map the pieces in Eclipse launch configuration. Do not forget that "-jar C:\jBOSS\EAP70\jboss-modules.jar" becomes "-cp C:\jBOSS\EAP70\jboss-modules.jar org.jboss.modules.Main" when the '-cp ...' is then the last piece of VM arguments, and "org.jboss.modules.Main" is the one class to define under the "Main" tab.